# Having trouble with complex Boolean Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm modelling my first car in Blender, a Porsche 911, and am starting detail work on my base model. I am trying to boolean out a hole so that my tail lights can sit just behind the mesh, just like the real car:[image]

But when I make a shape to boolean and add the modifier, I get a weird result like this:
[image]

I'm not sure why this happens, and have spent about an hour trying to fix it. I thought it might be due to the order of my modifiers, but have tried changing them and it didn't help. Maybe it is just my bad topology?

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the blend file if you want to have a look: [image]

Answer (score 3):

I just moved around your boolean in the Y-axis and changed the Boolean Difference Solver to Fast.

[image]

Comment: I've tried doing that but didn't change anything for me. Maybe its because I'm using Blender 3.1 instead of 3.2? Ill download the newest version now and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm using Blender 3.1. I'm new here in Blender Stack Exchange so I don't know how to upload the file I fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The normals of the boolean object are inverted, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate.